# How to perform wildcard search thtough encrypted text?

Tags: encryption, blowfish, pci-compliance

We have a website with tons of users, and because of PCI compliance issues we have to store their names encrypted (we use blowfish).
Now we need to have a wildcard search feature through their names in Admin Panel, which we can't decrypt in "in-query" way.

What general solutions exist to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible approaches.

The first works where the names themselves are not secret, but the data associated with them is.  You can set up a separate search index:

```
Name                 Record Number
----                 -------------
John Q. Public       12345
Hector H. Suarez     54321
Katherine T. Carson  98712
```

Search the index to find the relevant record number.  Retrieve and decrypt that particular record.

The second is for when the names themselves are secret.  Basically, treat the names like a password: hash each name with a cryptographically secure hash, like SHA-256.  You won't be able to use salt in this case, because it is for searching.  You might also need to pre-process searches as "John Q. Public" and "John Q Public" (no full stop) will hash to very different values.  This search index looks like:

```
Hashed Name          Record Number
-----------          -------------
1A2BFF68C ... CAF4   12345
5820BAA5F ... 67FA   54321
2039F288A ... 9BC2   98712
```

For each search you hash the name and look for that hash.  Again retrieve and decrypt the appropriate record.  You cannot do partial-name searches like, "retrieve all the Smiths," unless you are prepared to set up a number of similar indexes for all the main search possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
The second approach won't work, because it won't retrieve all Smiths, and regarding the first one, I also thought about that, now I'm waiting for response to see if it's OK for PCI stuff, will keep posted.

Thanks again.

Comment: You could retrieve all the Smiths if you pre-prepared a hashed index on surname only.  Searches would be limited to those fields for which you had already prepared indexes.  Free-form/wildcard searching would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

you use an indexing system such as Lucene, index every document (decrypted), and search over this index.

Comment: That is against PCI requirements, because we have all them decrypted in Lucene.

Comment: encrypt the lucene database, using the same key, only decrypt when required?

Answer (score 0):

Take a very careful read of the section of PCI-DSS titled "PCI DSS Applicaility Information" in PCI DSS version 2.0.

You should find from reading this that "PCI DSS requirements 3.3 and 3.4 apply only to the PAN". This could be your workaround for not having to encrypt the data other than the PAN - meaning the names could be stored in plain text.

This isn't necessarily best practice but is something to consider if you absolutely must have the functionality of being able to wildcard search through the text